# QTimeEdit: how to create an object of "QTime::setHMS(int, int, int, int)"?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am trying to set two timeEdits: "timeEdit" and "timeEdit_2". "timeEdit_2" take the current time as follow:

```
ui->timeEdit_2->setTime(QTime::currentTime());
```

meanwhile, "timeEdit" should be an hour early from "timeEdit_2". so I am doing the following:

```
int hour = (QTime::currentTime().hour())-1;
int minutes = QTime::currentTime().minute();
int second = QTime::currentTime().second();
QTime time = QTime::setHMS(hour, minutes,second);
ui->timeEdit->setTime(QTime(time));
```

but I get this error:

```
erroe:cannot call member function 'bool QTime::setHMS(int, int, int, int)' without object
```

How to create this object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtime.html#QTime-2) that takes directly the hours, minutes and seconds as parameters :

```
QTime time(hour, minutes,second);
ui->timeEdit->setTime(time);
```